# Abnormal behaviour of React useEffect Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I am facing an abnormal output on the browser from React while using useEffect hook.
I would request you to please have a look at the code. You can copy and paste the code on any online IDE that supports React to visualize the behavior on the browser.
I want the counter to increment after every 1 second. But with the code it stucks after 10.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const initialState = 0;
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(count + 1);
    }, 1000);

    // return () => {
    //   clearInterval(interval);
    // };
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{count}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I want to know the reason for that. Why is it happening?

But when I do cleanup with useEffect to do componentWillUnmoint() it behaves normal and renders the counter every second properly. I have intentionally comment cleanup part of code useEffect.

Comment: Why is what happening?

Comment: I want the counter to increment after every 1 second. But with the code it stucks after 10.

Comment: why do you want to rerender it every time?

Answer (score 4):

You are adding an interval on every render, soon enough, your thread will be overloaded with intervals.

I guess you wanted to run a single interval, its done by removing the closure on `count` by passing a function to state setter ("functional update"):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{count}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```